# AD Domain Controller Won't Boot

Tags: active-directory, restore

I run the network for a small organization.  We have a virtual host server (CentOS) using VirtualBox to host the AD Domain Controller / File Server (Windows Server 2012).  We recently had a power failure, and now I am getting an error on the AD Database (0xc00002e2) when booting.  I have found [How to fix Error 0xc00002e2 after rebooting Windows Domain Controller](https://support.hostway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001126259-How-to-fix-Error-0xc00002e2-after-rebooting-Windows-Domain-Controller) seems to be a good explanation on correcting the issue, but the local admin password I have doesn't seem to be correct.  I have also tried restoring the server and creating a new install from a restore, but nothing seems to be working.

Our AD is replicated to Azure AD--is it possible to restore the AD from Azure?  Is there another way to restore the AD without the DC local Administrator account?  Am I up the excrement water canal with no source of propulsion?

Comment: **Our AD is replicated to Azure AD** - Assuming you mean that you're running Azure AD Connect... your AD isn't replicated to Azure AD, it's synchronized to Azure AD. They are two different directories. You can't recover your on premises directory from your synchronized Azure AD directory.

Comment: How did you restore the server? Was this a full backup of the virtual machines? If so, what happens when you restore the entire virtual machine?

Comment: You can try to reset local admin password following - http://www.kieranlane.com/2013/09/18/resetting-administrator-password-windows-2012/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have only one domain controller? If yes, you should not; and this is why.
If your single DC doesn't work anymore, congratulations, you have just lost your Active Directory domain (unless you can fix it or you have a backup).

And no, Azure AD synchronization will **not** allow you to recover your domain; it's a one-way process, your AD rules over Azure AD when sync is enabled and there is no way to do the opposite.

Comment: It might also be a good point to convert the environment to AzureAD only. For a small business that doesn't have the resources to maintain a proper AD environment it's a very good alternative.

Comment: I considered converting to AzureAD only, but we have a couple Macs and local network file sharing doesn't seem to be supported by Azure AD.  I have rebuilt the AD without too much difficulty (and added a second DC).  Syncing to Azure may prove to be a bit trickier.